# Kali Linux 1.1.0a doesn't boot from USB

Tags: ubuntu, windows, dual-boot, kali-linux

I have Windows 8.1 and Ubuntu installed. I had ran boot-repair since the os selection menu wasn't showing.

A few days ago, I downloaded the latest version of Kali Linux. I used PowerISO to copy all the files to a 16GB usb stick(USB 3.0). I rebooted. In the menu when booting, I moved 'USB HDD' to the top of the list and saved.

This is exactly what I did when installing Ubuntu. With my USB stick inserted into the usb port, I hit the power button of my laptop... the purple grub menu showed up.

[image: Image taken from the internet]

I rebooted few times, but it still showed the grub menu. I booted into Ubuntu  and ran a md5 checksum. Everything is ok.

Any help?

Comment: Downvoted because the documentation to Kali Linux USB installation is easy to google.

Comment: @JodkaLemon I did read the documentation but I was on Windows so I don't want to install additional software(I have PowerISO)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just copying the files is not enough because you will miss the bootloader.

You should dd the image to the usb stick:

```
dd if=kali.iso of=/dev/sdX bs=4M; sync
```

to start it.

Be aware, that this will delete all data on the stick and the partition scheme will not be optimal.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're on Ubuntu, you can also use the [Startup Disk Creator.](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu) It's a bit easier to use than dd, IMHO.